# Some bluetooth problems makes my Ubuntu boot slowly and I can't use nor Bum nor Rcconf, any alternative?

Tags: boot

My computer boots very slow and I think I've got the problem. This is what dmesg says:

```
...
[   13.812524] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x2010 tx timeout
[   97.224904] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
...`
```

It looks like the bluetooth is responsible for it. As I don't know how to repair it and I don't need bluetooth at all, I decided to tell Ubuntu not to load it. So I've been looking for a tool to do that. Everyone talks about "bum" or "rcconf" but those packages aren't available for zesty.

Is there any alternative to those packages or do you know any other way to solve this problem?

Comment: If you turn bluetooth off, any difference? Slow boot... how slow, in seconds? I suspect something else is going on. Any other details that you can provide?

Comment: You can install systemd-ui as graphical interface for system. But I don't think, that the delay is coming from Bluetooth. Try `journalctl –b` to see what is taking so long in your boot process.

Comment: heynnema I posted part of the results of dmesg. If I am not wrong, it says that something related with the bluetooth is taking too long during the boot.
@SimonSudler Sudler I think that the pachage journalctl is not available for zenial. I used bootchart but I don't really understand it...
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6iZIQBHwEk4UFJHWjEwVGYxN28/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6iZIQBHwEk4OURDaWpDcTVnbk0/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I think, I see the problem in... you have some sort of bluetooth network device, that is not properly configured (e.g. no dhcp). The network-manger waits around 120s until it gives up on the device. Can you remove the device, to see if the boot process speeds up?